# Split AJAX response (JSON)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

How would I split the following AJAX response into three separate objects based on the attribute 'product_range' using JS/jQuery, i.e. one object array for all 'range-1' products, one for 'range-2' and so on?

```
[
   {
       title:         "Product 1",
       price:         "12.00",
       product_range: "range-1"
   },
   {
       title:         "Product 2",
       price:         "12.00",
       product_range: "range-2"
   },
   {
       title:         "Product 3",
       price:         "12.00",
       product_range: "range-3"
   }
]
```

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: @Siva To populate HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use reduce and push items into an object that holds arrays.

```js
    var items = [
       {
           title:         "Product 1",
           price:         "12.00",
           product_range: "range-1"
       },
       {
           title:         "Product 2",
           price:         "12.00",
           product_range: "range-2"
       },
       {
           title:         "Product 3",
           price:         "12.00",
           product_range: "range-3"
       }
    ];
    
    var grouped = items.reduce( function (obj, item) { 
       if (!obj[item.product_range]) obj[item.product_range] = [];
       obj[item.product_range].push(item);
       return obj;
    }, {});
    
    console.log(grouped);    
    console.log(grouped["range-1"]);
```

Comment: I think you're missing a `{` in your `if` statement.

Comment: @Ryan code is perfectly fine. { and } is not needed with an if. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Answer (score 0):

Use the method "filterByProductRange" to filter out the data by product_range.

```js
var obj = [
   {
       title:         "Product 1",
       price:         "12.00",
       product_range: "range-1"
   },
   {
       title:         "Product 2",
       price:         "12.00",
       product_range: "range-2"
   },
   {
       title:         "Product 3",
       price:         "12.00",
       product_range: "range-3"
   }
];



function filterByProductRange(data, product_range) {
  
  return data.filter(function(item) { return item['product_range'] == product_range; });
  }

var range1= filterByProductRange(obj, 'range-1');

console.log(range1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.map()` to achieve a similar result.

```
var range1 = new Object(),
    range2 = new Object(),
    range3 = new Object();

$.map(data, function(d){
        if (d.product_range === "range-1") {
         for (var i in d) {
        range1[i] = d[i];
       }
    }
});
```

Where `data` is your object array.

Here's a simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GentleMaN/hzvtpfsL/) to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean grouping your data by `product_range`, then:

```
//json is your json data
var result = {};
for(var i=0; i<json.length;i++)
{
  if(result[json[i].product_range] === undefined) result[json[i].product_range] = [];
  result[json[i].product_range].push(json[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should group by range.

```
var ranged = {};
var data = [{
  title: "Product 1",
  price: "12.00",
  product_range: "range-1"
}, {
  title: "Product 2",
  price: "12.00",
  product_range: "range-2"
}, {
  title: "Product 3",
  price: "12.00",
  product_range: "range-3"
}]

$.each(data, function(i, x) {
  if (ranged[x.product_range]) {
    ranged[x.product_range].push(x);
  } else {
    ranged[x.product_range] = [x];
  }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(ranged));
```

You should then be able to retrieve all object for a given range by querying the ranged object.